# MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA in Android 4.3 Jelly Bean MR2

Tags: android, mediastore

When I use this word in Android 4.3,it throws IllegalArgumentException,
because "_data" not exist.How can I solve this problem? The parameter mImageUri is an Image Uri.

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse(mImageUri), null, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
```

Comment: mImageUri is the Image uri

Comment: Did you find the solution? Even I am facing the same Issue.